# Texmaker: Compile keyboard shortcut

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

A simple question: Is there a keyboard shortcut to compile the document in Texmaker? E.g. like `Ctrl` + `Enter` for Overleaf? I've gotten quite used to it after switching from TeXworks, but couldn't find out if there is such a function on Texmaker too.

Comment: See the tools menu, the shortcut is listed on the right

Comment: Ah excellent, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need the "Tools" menu commands:

- Quick build : F1
- Latex : F2
- View dvi : F3
- Dvi->PS : F4
- View PS : F5
- Pdflatex : F6
- View Pdf : F7

Complete list at: http://texmaker.de/?page_id=34

Comment: Thanks for the link. That allowed me to change it to a different key bind